# Multi level hash ref in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I want to iterate following multilevel hash ref and want to create parent->child relationship along with drag/drop functionality.Following is the hash ref which I got from dumper.So I want to create a section and display all parent and child relationship information in which I can drag and drop child into its parent element only, also drag and drop each parent element to change the display order. but my first priority to display parent->child relations ship correctly.

hash is as follows:

```
my $hash  = {
          '4' => {
                   'forumid' => '136720',
                   'children' => {
                                   '7' => {
                                            'forumid' => '136997',
                                            'title' => 'under category',
                                            'is_category' => '0',
                                            'parentid' => '136720'
                                          }
                                 },
                   'title' => 'Android',
                   'is_category' => '0',
                   'parentid' => '-1'
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'forumid' => '136666',
                   'children' => {
                                   '5' => {
                                            'forumid' => '136954',
                                            'children' => {
                                                            '8' => {
                                                                     'forumid' => '137004',
                                                                     'title' => 'child of child',
                                                                     'is_category' => '0',
                                                                     'parentid' => '136954'
                                                                   }
                                                          },
                                            'title' => 'add child',
                                            'is_category' => '0',
                                            'parentid' => '136666'
                                          }
                                 },
                   'title' => 'Main Forum',
                   'is_category' => '0',
                   'parentid' => '-1'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'forumid' => '136719',
                   'title' => 'Nokia C2-01',
                   'is_category' => '1',
                   'parentid' => '-1'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'forumid' => '136665',
                   'children' => {
                                   '6' => {
                                            'forumid' => '136994',
                                            'children' => {
                                                            '9' => {
                                                                     'forumid' => '137012',
                                                                     'title' => 'another child',
                                                                     'is_category' => '0',
                                                                     'parentid' => '136994'
                                                                   }
                                                          },
                                            'title' => 'sub form under test forum',
                                            'is_category' => '0',
                                            'parentid' => '136665'
                                          }
                                 },
                   'title' => 'test',
                   'is_category' => '0',
                   'parentid' => '-1'
                 }
        };
```

and I need my output as follows:

```
<div id='136666'>Main Forum
    <div>
        <a href='136954'>add child</a>, <a href='137004'>child of child</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='136665'>test
    <div>
        <a href='136994'>sub form under test forum</a>, <a href='137012'>another child</a>
    </div>  
</div>
<div id='136719'>Nokia C2-01
    <div id='136720'>Android
        <div>
            <a href='136997'>under category</a> 
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

so that it should be look like i.e. child should be added into parent element separated with comma:

```
Main Forum
add child, child of child
test
sub form under test forum, another child
Nokia C2-01
Android
under category
```

here is the function for creating hash:

```
     sub subforumsTree {
    my $forums = shift; 
    my $pid = shift || ('-1' || '0');
    my $HASH;   
    foreach my $forum ( @{$forums}){
        #next if ($forum->{is_category});           
        if($forum->{parentid} eq $pid){
            $HASH->{$forum->{displayorder}} = {forumid=>$forum->{forumid},parentid=>$forum->{parentid},title=>$forum->{title},is_category=>$forum->{is_category}};  
            my $children =  &subforumsTree( $forums,$forum->{forumid} );
            if( $children ) {
               $HASH->{$forum->{displayorder}}->{'children'} = $children;
            }
        }
    }

     return $HASH;
}

here is the function which I tried for displaying elements:
sub adminforumsList {

    my $hash = shift;
    my $options = '';
    my $iter; 
    $iter = sub {
        my $hash = shift;
        my $indent = shift || '';
        foreach my $k (sort keys %{$hash}) {  
            my $v = $hash->{$k};
                        $options .= "<div id=cat_".$v->{forumid}." class=isDraggable>
                        <div class='col_buttons right' style='white-space: nowrap'>
                        <ul class='ipsControlStrip'>
                        <li class='i_add'>
                        <a href='#' title='New Forum...'>New Forum...</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='i_edit'>
                        <a href='#' title='Edit Settings...'>Edit Settings...</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class='ipsControlStrip_more ipbmenu' id='menum-26'>
                        <a href='#'>Options</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class='acp-menu' id='menum-26_menucontent' style='display: none'>
                        <li class='icon info'><a href='#'>Permissions...</a></li>
                        <li class='icon delete'><a href='#'>Delete Category...</a></li>
                        <li class='icon edit'><a href='#'>Edit as Forum...</a></li>
                        <li class='icon view'><a href='#'>Skin Options...</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div><div class='draghandle'>&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class='item_info'>
                        <img src='/images/icons/folder.png' />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class='larger_text'>$v->{title}</strong>                
                        </div>";
                        $options .= "<div id='cat_wrap_".$v->{forumid}. "' class='item_wrap'>";
                        $options .= "<div class='item ipsControlRow isDraggable' id='forum_".$v->{forumid}."'>";
                        $options .= "<table style='width: 100%'>
                        <tr>
                        <td style='width: 20px !important; vertical-align: top;'>
                            <div class='draghandle'>&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style=''>
                            <div class='item_info'>
                                <strong class='forum_name'>$v->{title}</strong>
                                <br />
                                <span class='desctext'>$v->{description}</span>
                            </div>
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                        </table></div></div></div>";

            if ($v->{children}){
                $iter->($v->{children}, $indent . "--");
            }
        }
    };
    $iter->($hash);
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Your examples are not yet self-consistent, and could do with simplifying - a lot of the data isn't required to answer your question. For instance your HTML has Android *inside* Nokia C2-01, but that is not how you have it in the hash. Also, could you be a little clearer on how you expect to resolve child-of-child elements - you appear to want to flatten them and only display one level of depth, correct? Finally, what Perl code have you tried?

Comment: actually hash keys are display order key  like 1,2,3 and 4 and I have to display all elements in this order so doesn't matter if we separate it from Android. firstly  I have used a function using recursion for a drop down but I have to change my approach and display it just as mentioned above.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: yes sure see above,  the function for creating hash first.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what you have tried, and your question isn't exactly clear which may mean that your question will be closed.

I'm not going to do too much programming for you, but I suggest you look into [Perl Object Oriented Programming](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).

Each forum can be an *object*, and one of the fields can be a hash of other forums. Programming OO Perl isn't that hard if you already understand about references. By defining each forum as a member of your forum class, you remove the tricky part of operating on a hash of hashes.

I would also suggest that you break your problem down into smaller pieces. Drag and Drop can be added once you have the basics of your code down. Do you want to output XML? It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. If you merely want to store your structure, you can use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html). If you pass it your forum structure, it will store the entire structure in a file, and you'll be able to read it back in. Storable is much easier to use than XML for these types of tasks, and it's a standard module.

However, if you must have it in XML, you should use one of the many [XML modules](http://cpan.perl.org/authors/id/E/EI/EISEN/perl-xml-modules.html) available in Perl

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but previously I used a recursion function for displaying same forum list in a drop down but now I have to change my approach according to my need which is mentioned above.

Comment: @RituSingh `$HASH->{$forum->{displayorder}} = {forumid=>$forum->{forumid},parentid=>$forum->{parentid},title=>$forum->{title},is_category=>$forum->{is_category}};` You have to actually maintain this. You'll find that defining your forum as an object, will make it a lot simpler the next time you have to _change your approach_.